# Keras の validation_split は交差検証でしょうか？

Tags: python, 深層学習, keras

Pythonを独学で勉強しているものです。

Kerasのコードで、

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, epochs=20000)
```

とした時、80%のデータが学習用に使用され、20%のデータがバリデーションに使用される、というエポックが20000回繰り返されて学習が行われると認識しています。

```
shuffle=True
```

としているため、バリデーション用データの選択がランダムになり、このコードは交差検証、もっというならk=5のk分割交差検証になると思っているのですが、合っておりますでしょうか。
Kerasのk分割交差検証用コードを調べてみると、Scikit-learnのKholdが使用されているコードなどが出てくるため、合っているかどうか不安になり、質問させていただきました。

初歩的な質問で申し訳ございませんが、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

**交差検証ではありません**。

`validation_split` は、**データセットのシャッフルをする前に**、指定した割合のデータをバリデーション用として切り出すための引数です<sup>1</sup>。また、バリデーションデータはデータセットの末尾から指定割合ぶんを取得しています<sup>2</sup>。このため、すべてのエポックで同じデータがバリデーションに使われており、抽出方法もランダム抽出ではありません。

`shuffle` は、学習用のデータセットをシャッフルする引数です。エポックごとに学習データをシャッフルすることで、損失が小さくなりやすいことが知られているため<sup>3,4</sup>、このような引数が設けられています。

Keras のドキュメンテーションでは、`model.fit` の引数について下記のとおり説明しています：

> - `validation_split`: 0から1の間の浮動小数点数．バリデーションデータとして使われる訓練データの割合．[中略] このバリデーションデータは，**シャッフルを行う前に**，与えられたxとyのデータの後ろからサンプリングされます．
> - `shuffle`: 真理値（**訓練データを**各試行 [エポック] の前にシャッフルするかどうか）または文字列（'batch'の場合）． [後略]
>
> *Keras ドキュメンテーション (https://keras.io/ja/models/model/) 、最終アクセス年月日: 2022-01-16。角カッコおよび強調は回答者が付加。*

Keras はK分割交差検証の機能を提供していません。ご指摘のとおり、scikit-learn など別のライブラリを利用する必要があります。

---

<sup>1 <sub>関連する箇所の実装は、[`model.fit`の定義](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/35504ff7a13e745d60f0c9ef6d6c97542df40e03/keras/engine/training.py#L1070) (GitHub) です。`validation_split` を引数とする処理が、`shuffle` の適用前に実行されていることがわかります。</sub></sup>
<sup>2 <sub>実装上は、[`validation_split`の処理](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/35504ff7a13e745d60f0c9ef6d6c97542df40e03/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L1456) (GitHub) のようになっています。</sub></sup>
<sup>3 <sub>シャッフルあり/なしの実験例: https://qiita.com/hikobotch/items/d8ff5bebcf70083de089</sub></sup>
<sup>4 <sub>なぜ損失が小さくなるのかの説明（英語）: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/311318</sub></sup>